# Pytorch: How to predict a 1D vector from a 2D vector/image?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I'm attempting use Pytorch to predict a 1D vector (a frame of **clean** speech data) using regression from a 2D vector (a sequence of frames of **noisy** speech data) - which has been done before. The sequence of frames provide temporal context for the frame to more accurately predict the clean frame. The vectors can be thought of as analogous to a 2D grayscale image and 1D grayscale image.

When the batch size is 64, window length is 5 and frame length is 257 the input tensor has a shape of [64, 1, 5, 257] and the target tensor has a shape of [64, 1, 1, 257].

There are some examples of this being done in TensorFlow, but none that I can find using Pytorch. This is my best attempt so far to replicate this paper (https://www.isca-speech.org/archive/Interspeech_2017/pdfs/1465.PDF).

```
def __init__(self, window_length, frame_length, batch_size):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 12, kernel_size=(1,13), stride=1, padding=(0,6)),
            # nn.BatchNorm2d(12),
            nn.ReLU())
        self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(12, 16, kernel_size=(1,11), stride=1, padding=(0,5)),
            # nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
            nn.ReLU())
        self.layer3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(16, 20, kernel_size=(1,9), stride=1, padding=(0,4)),
            # nn.BatchNorm2d(20),
            nn.ReLU())
        self.layer4 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(20, 24, kernel_size=(1,7), stride=1, padding=(0,3)),
            # nn.BatchNorm2d(24),
            nn.ReLU())
        self.layer5 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(24, 32, kernel_size=(1,7), stride=1, padding=(0,3)),
            # nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.ReLU())
        self.layer6 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(32, 24, kernel_size=(1,7), stride=1, padding=(0,3)),
            # nn.BatchNorm2d(24),
            nn.ReLU())
        self.layer7 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(24, 20, kernel_size=(1,9), stride=1, padding=(0,4)),
            # nn.BatchNorm2d(20),
            nn.ReLU())
        self.layer8 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(20, 16, kernel_size=(1,11), stride=1, padding=(0,5)),
            # nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
            nn.ReLU())
        self.layer9 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(16, 12, kernel_size=(1,13), stride=1, padding=(0,6)),
            # nn.BatchNorm2d(12),
            nn.ReLU())
        self.conv_out = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(12, 1, kernel_size=(1,1), stride=1, padding=(0,0)),
            )
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(batch_size * window_length * frame_length, frame_length)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.layer1(x)
        out = self.layer2(out)
        out = self.layer3(out)
        out = self.layer4(out)
        out = self.layer5(out)
        out = self.layer6(out)
        out = self.layer7(out)
        out = self.layer8(out)
        out = self.layer9(out)
        out = self.conv_out(out)
        out = self.fc1(out)
        return out
```

Calling `.forward()` on this net results in the following error message:

`RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [320 x 257], m2: [82240 x 257]`

How can I reduce the output layer to 1x257 per sample to match the target (a single frame of length 257)?

Answer (score 0):

Heres a working example of your code.

```
class Net(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, window_length, frame_length, batch_size):
      super(Net, self).__init__()
      self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Conv2d(1, 12, kernel_size=(1,13), stride=1, padding=(0,6)),
          # nn.BatchNorm2d(12),
          nn.ReLU())
      self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Conv2d(12, 16, kernel_size=(1,11), stride=1, padding=(0,5)),
          # nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
          nn.ReLU())
      self.layer3 = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Conv2d(16, 20, kernel_size=(1,9), stride=1, padding=(0,4)),
          # nn.BatchNorm2d(20),
          nn.ReLU())
      self.layer4 = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Conv2d(20, 24, kernel_size=(1,7), stride=1, padding=(0,3)),
          # nn.BatchNorm2d(24),
          nn.ReLU())
      self.layer5 = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Conv2d(24, 32, kernel_size=(1,7), stride=1, padding=(0,3)),
          # nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
          nn.ReLU())
      self.layer6 = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Conv2d(32, 24, kernel_size=(1,7), stride=1, padding=(0,3)),
          # nn.BatchNorm2d(24),
          nn.ReLU())
      self.layer7 = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Conv2d(24, 20, kernel_size=(1,9), stride=1, padding=(0,4)),
          # nn.BatchNorm2d(20),
          nn.ReLU())
      self.layer8 = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Conv2d(20, 16, kernel_size=(1,11), stride=1, padding=(0,5)),
          # nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
          nn.ReLU())
      self.layer9 = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Conv2d(16, 12, kernel_size=(1,13), stride=1, padding=(0,6)),
          # nn.BatchNorm2d(12),
          nn.ReLU())
      self.conv_out = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Conv2d(12, 1, kernel_size=(1,1), stride=1, padding=(0,0)),
          )
      self.fc1 = nn.Linear(window_length * frame_length, frame_length)

  def forward(self, x):

      out = self.layer1(x)
      out = self.layer2(out)
      out = self.layer3(out)
      out = self.layer4(out)
      out = self.layer5(out)
      out = self.layer6(out)
      out = self.layer7(out)
      out = self.layer8(out)
      out = self.layer9(out)
      out = self.conv_out(out)
      out = out.view(-1, 5*257)
      out = self.fc1(out)
      return out
```

Changes I made :

- Changed the definition of the Linear layer. In Pytorch, you dont explicitly use the batch size in your model formulation.Your model formulation should be such that it can handle any value of batch size. Furthermore, defining Linear layer based on batch_size is wrong. Linear layer is defined only the true shape of the inputs.
- Used view to reshape your output after the convolution layer

I referred the following tensorflow code [RCED](https://github.com/linan2/TensorFlow-speech-enhancement/blob/master/models/resnet_rced.py) to make these changes. Though I do find it a bit different from the paper description, which says that it uses fully convolutional layers. But I goes, they are both almost similar.

Comment: I've added the forward function. 

I don't need to just reshape the output but remove some of the layer's elements.